# What would you call this smile?

Tags: single-word-requests

Let's say that you catch your child eating a box of cookies alone. You scold him and forbid him from eating it as it is not for him to eat alone. Later, when the child is playing with his younger sibling, he realises the loophole. You forbade him from eating alone but he can have it with someone else.

> Charlie saw a _______ smile spread on Devon's face as he looked at his sibling.

I am looking for a word to fill that blank. I am looking for something which would mean cunning or scheming, but not those words as they make it seem like an adult doing something nefarious. This is just an innocent child who has figured out a loophole to his advantage. There is no evil intent here. Do note that since this is in third person, so Charlie does not know what Devon is thinking only that something fishy is up.

Comment: "Devious", perhaps?

Comment: Guys...as I always say, if the Q is worth an answer, it is also worthy of  an upvote.

Comment: "Charlie caught the dawning of a bright idea spread across Devon's face as he took note of his sibling in the other room."

Comment: Not an adjective, but I feel like the word “smirk” is appropriate here. Not putting this as an answer though, because you didn’t ask for alternates (and I would personally not say “…a smirk spread…”).

Comment: "Lawyer's smile", if we must coin a new term.

Comment: An enterprising smile, an anticipatory smile, a mischievous smile, a plotting smile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sly: having or showing a cunning and deceitful nature.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. This appears to come from [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/sly). Please note that **all** quotes must be [obviously shown as quotations and accompanied by citations](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). You should also justify your choice in your own words.

Answer (score 3):

- Charlie saw a **knowing** smile spread on Devon's face as he looked at his sibling.

From [AHD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/knowing):

> *knowing*: ...
>
> 2. Showing clever awareness and resourcefulness; shrewd and worldly:
>    *Even so knowing a young ruffian as William Chaloner would have had no
>    preparation for the shock of London* (Thomas Levenson).
> 3. Suggestive of secret or private knowledge: *a knowing glance* [/smile, Lexico]

Comment: I feel like a "knowing smile" is often used to mean "I know what you've thinking", often for empathy. It would be aimed at a person.

Answer (score 2):

> ***a ***smug*** smile/grin***

***Smug***

[Cambridge online](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/smug)

> too pleased or satisfied about something you have achieved or something you know:

> Also: a smug grin

[***Grin***](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/grin-smile-from-ear-to-ear) actually refers to:

> smile broadly, especially in an unrestrained manner and with the mouth open.

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/smug)

> Charlie saw a ***smug*** grin/smile spread *across* Devon's face as he looked at his sibling

However, I am suggesting... :

***smirk***

> a smile that expresses satisfaction or pleasure about having done something or knowing something that is not known by someone else:

[-Cambridge online](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/smirk)

> Charlie saw a ***smirk*** spread *across* Devon's face as he looked at his sibling

[image]

This is non-judgemental, and seems to suit a child's  viewpoint. It's like a repressed "yenh, yenh".

Answer (score 0):

*Satisfied*

Full of or showing satisfaction: a very satisfied customer; a satisfied look.

AHD https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=satisfied

Answer (score -1):

I would use the word *cheeky*:

> disrespectful in speech or behaviour; impudent: a cheeky child.

[[The Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/cheeky)]

Answer (score -1):

***Sardonic.***

Mocking, cynical, and scornful.

> humorous in an unkind way that shows you do not respect someone or something:

[Cambridge online](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sardonic)

A little harsh, perhaps, but we don't really know Devon.

> 'A sardonic smile spread on Devon's face...'.

As used by Homer [needs update].

Comment: The OP said "...but not those words as they make it seem like an adult doing something nefarious.". BTW, Not my DV.

Comment: @Cascabel - thanks for feedback. I'm sick and tired on SE of dvs with no justification shown. Anyone can do that anonymously, but it helps no-one.

Comment: I'm sorry, Some actions like that are due to political issues here. That said, could you please at least provide a citation and source, and maybe a link to support your selection? The community here is a little difficult  to satisfy until you get with the "culture".

Comment: I would especially love to see the bit from Homer that applies...sometimes it is the oddball reference that succeeds here.

Comment: +1 I have edited this A to bring it into guidelines as far as I understand them. If you are unhappy with my edits you can always "roll them back".

Answer (score -3):

This is a **shit eating grin**, as defined by the OED:

> A broad grin expressing uncontrollable delight or (self-)satisfaction, esp. characterized by awareness of having got away with something normally considered outrageous or improper.

Note that it’s always a *grin* (not a *smile*).

Comment: It's worth noting that the OED adds the comment *"coarse slang (originally U.S.)"* - I've not heard it in British English.

Comment: But he was eating *cookies*...